# How do I simplify this implementation of split()?

Tags: java, split

Need help simplifying split() implementation. Unfortunately split() is not covered as part of AP JAVA.  I need to present to high school students and need a simple easy to understand approach. Here's what I've come up with so far but was wondering if I am missing something obvious.

```
String[] tokens = new String[3]; 
boolean exit = false;

do{ 
   System.out.print( "Please enter first name, last name and password to logon or 
                      create a new account \n" + "use a space to seperate entries, 
                      no commas                                                  : ");

   input = kboard.nextLine();
   int spaces = 0;

   if(input.length() == 0) exit = true;
   if(!exit){                
       //tokens = input.split(" ");
       int idx;
       int j = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < input.length();){
           idx = input.indexOf(" ",i);
           if(idx == -1 || j == 3) {
               i = input.length();
               tokens[j] = input.substring(i);
           }else{                        
               tokens[j] = input.substring(i,idx);                       
               i = idx + 1;
           }
           j++;
       }
       spaces = j - 1 ;                
   }

 // check we have 2 and no blank line     
}while (spaces != 2 && exit == false);
```

Comment: What split implementation? What is this supposed to do? (Also here are the docs for [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: I don't think this could be interpreted as simplification of split() method but rather an opposite occurrence.

Comment: Why don't you just keep iterating until `indexOf(" ")` returns -1 and collect all the substrings into a list? That should be quite a simple loop.

Comment: Maybe better, more concise and succinct approach would be using Java 8 streams for your purpose?

Comment: “If I am missing something obvious” is a very poor and unspecific question so I downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new *Split* implementation from scratch, that at least in my opinion (subjective) is "simpler" to comprehend. You may or may not find it useful.

```
public static String[] split(String input, char separator) {
    // Count separator (spaces) to determine array size.
    int arrSize = (int)input.chars().filter(c -> c == separator).count() + 1;
    String[] sArr = new String[arrSize];

    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) { // Checks each char in string.
        if (c == separator) { // If c is sep, increase index.
            sArr[i] = sb.toString();
            sb.setLength(0); // Clears the buffer for the next word.
            i++;
        }
        else { // Else append char to current word.
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    sArr[i] = sb.toString(); // Add the last word (not covered in the loop).
    return sArr;
}
```

I assumed you wanted to use primitive arrays for teaching, otherwise, I would have returned an ArrayList to further simplify. If StringBuilder is too complicated for your students, you can replace it with normal string-concatenation (less efficient and bad practice).